# Constants as method arguments PHP

Tags: php, function, constants

Is it possible to find out which constant has been passed as an argument?

**Example**

```
<?php
define( 'POINTS_REQUEST_ADD',                '3' );
define( 'POINTS_REQUEST_DONE',               '5' );
define( 'POINTS_REQUEST_REACTIVATE',         '1' );
define( 'POINTS_REQUEST_UPLOAD',             '3' );

public static function addPoints( $points )
{
      switch($points) {
        case POINTS_REQUEST_ADD:
            ;// code
        case POINTS_REQUEST_DONE:
            ;// code
        // ....
        }
    }        
}

addPoints(POINTS_REQUEST_ADD);
```

In this case `$points` only contains the value (1, 3 or 5) and I can't think of any way to get the correct constant name out of it. if the value is `3` it could be `POINTS_REQUEST_ADD` or `POINTS_REQUEST_UPLOAD`.

Comment: No, not possible if not unique. Constants are just placeholders so you can remeber names insteadt of cryptic numbers.

Comment: If two constants have the same value, they're the same value and are interchangeable. If you want unique constants, give them unique values.

Comment: thanks. I know they work as a placeholder. Just hoped there may be a way

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to achieve exactly what you suggset, as these constants are passed by value.

So, instead create an Enum (enumerated) type which you can pass by reference, and which will contain any properties (number values etc) that you want to receive.

Unfortunately PHP doesn't have native Enums, but you can easily web-search for PHP-enums which will show you many different ways that people have constructed Enum-functionality.

Best of luck.

Comment: Why the down vote? Passing enumerated types is a perfectly suitable solution.